# How to access an array thread safely in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, thread-safety

Are operations on arrays in Java thread safe?

If not how to make access to an array thread safe in Java for both reads and writes?

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operation on array in java is not thread safe. Instead you may use `ArrayList` with `Collections.synchronizedList()`

Suppose we are trying to populate a synchronized ArrayList of String. Then you can add item to the list like -

```
List<String> list = 
         Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

       //Adding elements to synchronized ArrayList
       list.add("Item1");
       list.add("Item2");
       list.add("Item3");
```

Then access them from a `synchronized` block like this -

```
synchronized(list) {
       Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); 
       while (iterator.hasNext())
       System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Or you may use a thread safe variant of ArrayList - [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html). A good example can be found [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-synchronize-arraylist-in-java-with-example/).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 5):

You will not get an invalid state when changing arrays using multiple threads. However if a certain thread has edited a value in the array, there is no guarantee that another thread will see the changes. Similar issues occur for non-volatile variables.

Answer (score 1):

array operations are not threadsafe. you can either lock on a field, i would recommend to add a field e.g. named LOCK and do the

```
void add(){
 syncronized(LOCK) {
  // add
 }
}

void get(int i){
 synchronized(LOCK){ 
   // return
 }
}
```

or simply use

```
java.util.concurrent.*
```